How can I implement a custom button?
In an Angular9 application, I am creating a Timeline and would like to add some action buttons ('OK', 'cancel'...).
But when I write the function in HTML, Angular removes the javascript for safety.
How to implement javasript buttons or calls from a TimelineJS event?
Button implementation:
  private getButtons(acaoPlano: AcaoPlano): string {
    let o = '';
    o += '<div class="timeline-row">';
    o += `  <div class="btn-top-space">
              <button class='timeline-button timeline-button-secondary'>Cancelar</button>
              <button class='timeline-button timeline-button-success btn-left-space' id='botao-realizar'>Realizar</button>
            </div>`;
    o += '</div>'

    return o;
  }

The only way I could make it work was the following, but although it worked, I found it very gimmicky.
Does anyone know another way to do it?
  private timelineDidLoad(): void {
    this.setupIframeOnClickHandler();
  }


  private setupIframeOnClickHandler(): void {
    $('a[target="timelineIframeClickHijacker"]').bind('click', this.setupIframeOnClickHandlerImpl.bind(this));
  }

  private setupIframeOnClickHandlerImpl(e: any): void {
    const params = e.target.attributes.href;
    this.executarFuncaoDaTimeline(params);

    e.stopPropagation();
    setTimeout(() => {
      const timelineIframeClickHijacker: any = document.getElementById('timelineIframeClickHijacker');
      timelineIframeClickHijacker.src = '';
    }, 0);
  }

  private executarFuncaoDaTimeline(data: any): void {
    if ( data?.nodeValue ) {
      console.log('data.nodeValue', data.nodeValue);
    }
    this.toasterService.warning('Esta funcionalidade está em desenvolvimento.', 'Por favor, tente novamente dentro de alguns dias!');
  }


Can you add StackBlitz example?

First I recommend you to add the html code in an html sheet like button.component.html. I create an example with some code for you to add it to your application.
Example of your main app html code:
<div [innerHtml]="codeHtmlButton"> 

Example of button with your code:
private createHtmlButton(){
this.codeHtmlButton = `<div class="timeline-row">
         <div class="btn-top-space">
                  <button class='timeline-button timeline-button-secondary'>Cancelar</button>
                  <button class='timeline-button timeline-button-success btn-left-space' id='botao-realizar' (click)="clickHandler()">Realizar</button>
                </div>
    </div>`
}

    

In your  button.component.ts:
private clickHandler(): void {
    this.setupIframeOnClickHandler();
  }

Like that you will have a more organized code, you can have control of the execution that you need. You can add more or less functions, depending on your needs. I hope this can help you to have a simpler code and create what you want.

You might need DomSanitizer API for this. Just an example if you choose to do it this way


import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: `<div [innerHTML]="buttons"></div>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  buttons: SafeHtml;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.buttons = this.getButtons();
  }

  private getButtons(): SafeHtml {
    let htmlContent = `
      <div class="timeline-row">
        <div class="btn-top-space">
          <button class="timeline-button timeline-button-secondary">Cancelar</button>
          <button class="timeline-button timeline-button-success btn-left-space" id="botao-realizar">Realizar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlContent);
  }
}



